# SSMS: How to find columns with similar names, but different data types

Tags: sql, validation, sql-server-2008, metadata, information-schema

How to find columns with similar names, but different data types within the predefined scope of tables?

The Goal: **to verify columns metadata within a project**.

For example: column `deal_id` is used in 3 tables.

I want to be sure that deal_id metadata is everywhere the same.

To avoid following:

- table**1**.deal_id is **n**varchar(50)
- table**2**.deal_id is  varchar(50)
- table**3**.deal_id is **n**varchar(**6**0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this (query returns the `information_schema.columns` for the columns with the same name but different metadata ):

```
;with
    t1 as       -- get tables with the same column names
    (   select *
            , count(*) over(partition by column_name) clm_cnt
        from information_schema.columns        
        where TABLE_NAME like '%'  -- specify scope of your tables  here, otherwise it will look within entire DB
    ),
    t2 as  -- get flags - if amount of distinct types/lengths/etc are >1
    (   select *
            ,cast(clm_cnt - count(*) over(partition by column_name,COLUMN_DEFAULT          ) as bit) is_diff_COLUMN_DEFAULT            
            ,cast(clm_cnt - count(*) over(partition by column_name,IS_NULLABLE             ) as bit) is_diff_IS_NULLABLE             
            ,cast(clm_cnt - count(*) over(partition by column_name,DATA_TYPE               ) as bit) is_diff_DATA_TYPE               
            ,cast(clm_cnt - count(*) over(partition by column_name,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH) as bit) is_diff_CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
            ,cast(clm_cnt - count(*) over(partition by column_name,CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH  ) as bit) is_diff_CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH  
            ,cast(clm_cnt - count(*) over(partition by column_name,NUMERIC_PRECISION       ) as bit) is_diff_NUMERIC_PRECISION       
            ,cast(clm_cnt - count(*) over(partition by column_name,NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX ) as bit) is_diff_NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX 
            ,cast(clm_cnt - count(*) over(partition by column_name,NUMERIC_SCALE           ) as bit) is_diff_NUMERIC_SCALE           
            ,cast(clm_cnt - count(*) over(partition by column_name,DATETIME_PRECISION      ) as bit) is_diff_DATETIME_PRECISION      
            ,cast(clm_cnt - count(*) over(partition by column_name,COLLATION_NAME          ) as bit) is_diff_COLLATION_NAME          
        from t1
        where clm_cnt>1
    )
select * 
from t2 
where 1=1
and 
(   0
    --| is_diff_COLUMN_DEFAULT   
    --| is_diff_IS_NULLABLE       
    | is_diff_DATA_TYPE                    
    | is_diff_CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH 
    | is_diff_CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH   
    | is_diff_NUMERIC_PRECISION        
    | is_diff_NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX  
    | is_diff_NUMERIC_SCALE            
    | is_diff_DATETIME_PRECISION       
    | is_diff_COLLATION_NAME          
)>0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the column names with differences with a query on `information_schema.column`.  For the attributes you have highlighted:

```
select column_name
from information_schema.columns c
group by column_name
having min(data_type) <> max(data_type) or
       coalesce(min(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH), -1) <> coalesce(max(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH), -1) or
       coalesce(min(NUMERIC_PRECISION), -1) <> coalesce(max(NUMERIC_PRECISION), -1) or
       coalesce(min(NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX), -1) <> coalesce(max(NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX), -1) or
       coalesce(min(NUMERIC_SCALE), -1) <> coalesce(max(NUMERIC_SCALE), -1) or
       coalesce(min(DATETIME_PRECISION), -1) <> coalesce(max(DATETIME_PRECISION), -1) ;
```

You probably also want to include:

- `CHARACTER_SET_NAME`
- `COLLATION_NAME`

However, if you are always working with default character sets and collations, this might not apply to your database.

Nullability is probably not relevant.